# How to save the result of a SQL query in a variable in C#.net?

Tags: c#, sql

```
namespace Hotel
{
    public partial class Billing : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public Billing()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Billing_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Projects\\c# assignments\\Hotel Manager\\Hotel\\database\\master.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            //loadData();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            int rno = Int32.Parse(txtRoom.Text);


            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(ItemRate) FROM logs WHERE RoomNo=" + rno +"";
            int amt = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();   //arror is at this part

       //ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized.

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO bill VALUES('" + txtBillNo.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtRoom.Text.ToString() + "','" + amt.ToString() + "')";
            con.Close();
            txtBillNo.Text = "";
            txtRoom.Text = "";
            BillView bv = new BillView();
            bv.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

please help me with this error i am not able to store the the SQL query result into a variable???

Comment: You are setting your connection-string on another method whilst you are using empty con object in button event.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You are open for [SQL-Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Don't concatenate strings to build your query. Instead use SQL-Parameters.
2. Use [`using-statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for you connection (and everything else implementing `IDisposable`). Dispose will also close the connection, with `using` even on error.
3. The reason for the exception is that you don't have initialized the connection of the `SqlCommand` since you have't specified the connection. You can use the [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection.aspx) or the appropriate [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a.aspx).

Here's an example:

```
int amt;  
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    var sql = "SELECT SUM(ItemRate) FROM logs WHERE RoomNo = @RoomNo";
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNo", Int32.Parse(txtRoom.Text));
        con.Open();
        amt = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to just *open* the connection;
You need to associate `con` with `cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as the error described, you haven't set the [`Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection.aspx) property of your `SQLCommand`.

Try adding:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

before you call `ExecuteScalar()`.

Answer (score 1):

You've opened up a SqlConnection, but you haven't told the SqlCommand object to use it. Try adding this line:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

before you execute your query.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code you show - esp. some seroius security problems, I strongly advise you to read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and prepared statements/parameters and [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Just some quick correction/comments:

```
namespace Hotel
{
    public partial class Billing : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public Billing()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Billing_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Projects\\c# assignments\\Hotel Manager\\Hotel\\database\\master.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            //loadData();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Projects\\c# assignments\\Hotel Manager\\Hotel\\database\\master.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            con.Open();
            int rno = Int32.Parse(txtRoom.Text);

            cmd.Connection = con; // This solves the problem you see
            // HERE you SHOULD use a SQL paramter instead of appending strings to build your SQL !!!
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(ItemRate) FROM logs WHERE RoomNo=" + rno +"";
            int amt = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();   //arror is at this part


            // HERE you SHOULD use a SQL paramter instead of appending strings to build your SQL !!!
            // Another point: you build an INSERT but never execute it ?!?
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO bill VALUES('" + txtBillNo.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtRoom.Text.ToString() + "','" + amt.ToString() + "')";
            con.Close();
            txtBillNo.Text = "";
            txtRoom.Text = "";
            BillView bv = new BillView();
            bv.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the connection string inside your button1_click.

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\Projects\\c# assignments\\Hotel Manager\\Hotel\\database\\master.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

Also there are many things wrong in your code. It works this way

```
{
  // Create Connection Object  
  // Provide connection object with Connection string
  // Create command object
  // Open connection
  // Execute command
  // Close connection
  // Dispose connection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Connection String HERE"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlcmd= new SqlCommand())
            {
                sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon;            
                sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(ItemRate) FROM logs WHERE RoomNo=@rno";
                slqcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rno", rno);
                try
                {
                    sqlcon.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your Error Here");
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

This will be helpful I think and its more safe